# onAdaptiveCardInvoke method isn't triggered on Bot Framework Emulator / JavaScript - Bot Framework SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards, botframeworkemulator

For MS Teams chatbot on Bot Framework SDK, I was trying to invoke an event by onAdaptiveCardInvoke method by Adaptive Cards. I can do this on MS Teams but on Bot Framework Emulator, this method is not executed at all.